# Forcing a TFS checkin of a file via C#

Tags: checkin

How can I specify that I ALWAYS want the local file to replace the server copy even if the TFS copy is newer?

```
if (pendingChanges.GetUpperBound(0)>-1)
   ChangeSetNumber = workspace.CheckIn(pendingChanges, filename);
```

I can see from the intelisense that I can specify **checkinoptions** as a parameter of the CheckIn method, I just cannot find what I need to put in to have it always check in and ignore any conflict I might come up with.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: I found a command TF RESOLVE "item" /auto:AcceptYours /recursive  So I guess my revised question would be is there a programming equivalent to the /auto:AcceptYours switch?**

NecroEDIT: process the conflicts before doing the checkin

```
Conflict[] conflicts = workspace.QueryConflicts(new string[] { TFSProject }, true);

foreach (Conflict conflict in conflicts)
{
    conflict.Resolution = Resolution.AcceptTheirs;
    workspace.ResolveConflict(conflict);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing a merge rather than replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkins are atomic - either they all succeed or they all fail.  **If there are any conflicts that need to be resolved before the check in, the check in operation will throw an exception.** (Documentation)

You have to evaluate checkin for conflicts and then resolve the CheckinConflicts by Workspace.ResolveConflict Method. 
ResolveConflict expects CheckinConflict, and result of the EvaluateCheckin (which is CheckinEvaluationResult) includes CheckinConflicts.

[This page](http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/archive/2006/03/20/evaluate-checkin.aspx) may help.

Note: checkinoptions is not related with what you are asking.

Hope this helps.